# Why node js express route never stops running

Tags: node.js, express

I have made a route in express and it works below is the code snippet:

In **app.js** I have added:

```
var generateOrders      = require('./routes/generateOrders');
app.use('/generate-orders', generateOrders);
```

In **generateOrders.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var generateOrdersServices = require('../services/generateOrders')

router.get('/get-orders', function (req, res) {

    generateOrdersServices.getOrders(function (errGenerateOrders, responseGenerateOrders) {

        if(errGenerateOrders){
            console.log(errGenerateOrders);
            res.render(errGenerateOrders);
            return;
        }
        else{
            console.log(responseGenerateOrders);
            res.render(responseGenerateOrders);
            return;
        }

    })
})
```

Now when I hit http://localhost:4000/generate-orders/get-orders It does not stop ever.
My code generate a log file, where I add all the input and when I hit this route it keeps on adding output to the log file again and again.Also in terminal everything keeps on printing again and again.

below is my code which I am using to generate a log file for my console output:

```
/*************************Log Console **********************/

var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(base_log_path+'/getorders/getorders'+year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'-'+hours+'-'+minutes+'-'+seconds+'.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(d) { //
    log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
    log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};
/*************************Log Console **********************/
```

Please suggest some solution.

**Update**

**generateOrdersServices.getOrders:**

```
var getOrders = function(callback){

    exportedTradeIds(storename,function(err_processedList, tradeIds){
        if(err_processedList){
            console.log("Error in getting Processed trade ids from exported table error is: "+err);
            return callback('Error in getting Processed trade ids from exported table error is: '+err);

        }
        else if(tradeIds == 0)
        {
            console.log('No exported trade Ids');
            return callback('No exported trade Ids');
        }
        else
        {
            jdp_tb_trade.getJstTrades('WAIT_BUYER_CONFIRM_GOODS', 900, 30, 'tmall_i18n', tradeIds, function(err_jdp, jdp_tb_trades){

                if(err_jdp)
                {
                    callback('Error in jdp_trade_response. Error is: '+err_jdp);
                    return;
                }
                if(!jdp_tb_trades)
                {
                    callback(null, 'No result found from remote database.');
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                     for ( i in jdp_tb_trades) {
                        if(i == 1)
                        {
                             processConsign(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid,
                                 function (err_process_consign, lpnumber) {
                                     if (err_process_consign) {
                                         console.log("Some error occurred in processConsign. Error is:" + err_process_consign);

                                         var jdp_response_json_parsed = JSON.parse(jdp_tb_trades[i].jdp_response);

                                         //Check if generate XML is enabled from admin end.
                                         configuration.getOneByKey('generateXml', function (err_configuration, result_configuration) {
                                             if (err_configuration) {
                                                 console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled/disabled - No response.')
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 if (result_configuration.value == 'true') {
                                                     console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                                                     generateXml(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, function (err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml) {

                                                         if (err_generate_xml) {
                                                             return callback(err_generate_xml);
                                                         }
                                                         else {
                                                             return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                                                         }
                                                     });
                                                 }
                                                 else{
                                                     console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         });
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         console.log("response from processConsign:Lpnumber" + lpnumber);
                                         var jdp_response_json_parsed = JSON.parse(jdp_tb_trades[i].jdp_response);

                                         //Check if generate XML is enabled.
                                         configuration.getOneByKey(
                                             'generateXml',
                                             function (err_configuration, result_configuration) {
                                                 if (err_configuration) {
                                                     console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled/disabled - No response.')
                                                 }
                                                 else {
                                                     if (result_configuration.value == 'true')
                                                     {
                                                         console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                                                         generateXml(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, function (err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml) {
                                                             if (err_generate_xml)
                                                             {
                                                                 return callback(err_generate_xml);
                                                             }
                                                             else
                                                             {
                                                                 return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                                                             }

                                                             });
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                                                     }
                                                }
                                            });

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
             }
         })

};

module.exports = {

    getOrders: function (callback) {


            getOrders(function(err_getOrders, getOrdersResponse){

            if(err_getOrders){

                console.log("generate Order process error:"+err_getOrders);
                return callback(err_getOrders);
            }
            else{
                console.log("generate Order process success:"+getOrdersResponse);
                return callback(null, getOrdersResponse);
            }
        });
    },

}
```

I have omitted some code from **generateOrdersServices.getOrders** as it is not allowed to post that much code here.

Comment: Ignoring the monkey patching of `console.log` (which is not a good idea), you should show how `generateOrdersServices.getOrders` is defined.

Comment: DEBUG, is the solution. Try this https://blog.hospodarets.com/nodejs-debugging-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: @mscdex I have made an update.

Comment: Unrelated tip: use proper instances of `Error` or one of its subclasses for error arguments instead of just strings.

Comment: The problem most likely lies in one of the many async code paths where you are not calling `callback()` in one conditional branch or another. Try adding those missing calls and see if the problem persists.